# Simple piece of C I can't make sense of

Tags: c, fork

Sorry for this, just can't seem to make sense of what is going on in this little piece of C :

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
        int i;
        if (fork()) { /* must be the parent */
            for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
            printf("\t\t\tParent %d\n", i);
        }
        else { /* must be the child */
            for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
                printf("Child %d\n", i);
        }
    }
```

As I understand it, it will print child 1000 times and parent 1000 times, but apparently it is much more complex and I must fully understand it ! Would anyone please be able to explain it to me ? Also, how would I change the program such that the parent and the child execute different computation?

Thanks a lot for your help with this :)

Comment: This looks like plain C. If this is C++, don't tag it as C. They are not the same language despite an ancestral relationship.

Comment: FWIW, `fork()` is a system function, not standard C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fork() creates a new process. So from that point on, there will be two separate processes that both continue from the point of code where the fork() was. In the main process fork() returns the PID of the new child process and in the child process it returns zero. So the code will execute different branches of the if statement in different processes.

Please also remember that new process is not the same thing as thread. Those processes won't have any global variables or similar things in common but they are completely separate. But they otherwise they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

The `fork()` function spawns a new process, with an exact copy of the memory of the original "parent" process.  Both processes continue to execute from the same point, but `fork()` returns 0 for the child, and non-zero for the parent.  So the parent executes the first loop, and the child executes the second loop.

Note that as there is nothing synchronising the parent and the child, the order that you see the strings displayed on screen will be essentially random.

Comment: What will happen when you do this? `while(1){fork();}`

Comment: @Time: Yes, in theory.  You'll get an exponentially growing number of threads, until your machine grinds to a halt, or the OS starts shedding existing processes.

Comment: think I'm gonna try it and see what happens. I'd love to see a Linux kernel panic as I've never seen one before. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `fork()` function generates what is called a child process.  The child process is a clone of the process that called `fork()` in the first place.  It even starts executing at the same place the parent process left off, which is right after calling `fork()`.

The only difference is that `fork()` will return `true` (or zero) for the parent process and `false` (or non-zero) for the child process.  That means the parent process, after calling `fork()`, will execute the first part of the conditional.  The child process will start executing the second part of the conditional.

Each one will print 1000 times as they are scheduled by the operating system, and each will eventually terminate when they reach the end of the main method.